# python memory leak in linked list with UIDs

Tags: python, memory-leaks, linked-list, garbage-collection

I am creating a linked list such that removing of items is not taking O(n^2) as discussed in: https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/p98v56/i_was_surprised_at_how_slow_listpop_is_and/

I created a linked list with index such that i can quickly remove and insert items. However, it seems that I don't clean properly when removing elements. i can't seem to find it.

This is my linked list code:

```
class ListItem:
    def __init__(self, data, prev=None, next=None):
        self.data = data
        self.prev = prev
        self.next = next

    def __del__(self):
        #del self.data
        #del self.next
        #del self.prev
        pass


class LinkedList:

    def __init__(self):
        self.head: ListItem = None
        self.tail: ListItem = None
        self.index = {}

    def append(self, data, uid):
        if uid in self.index:
            raise('exist')
        if self.tail is None:
            # this is the first item added
            new_item = ListItem(data)
            self.tail: ListItem = new_item
        else:
            # items already exist
            new_item = ListItem(data, prev=self.head)
            self.head.next = new_item

        self.head: ListItem = new_item

        self.index[uid] = new_item

    def append_start(self, data, uid):
        if uid in self.index:
            raise('exist')
        if self.tail is None:
            # this is the first item added
            new_item = ListItem(data)
            self.head: ListItem = new_item
        else:
            # items already exist
            new_item = ListItem(data, next=self.tail)
            self.tail.prev = new_item

        self.tail = new_item
        self.index[uid] = new_item

    def insert(self, place, data, uid):
        if uid in self.index:
            raise('exist')
        pos = self.tail
        while place > 0:
            pos = pos.next
            place -= 1
        new_item = ListItem(data, prev=pos.prev, next=pos)

        if pos.prev:
            pos.prev.next = new_item
        pos.prev = new_item
        self.index[uid] = new_item

    def remove(self, uid):
        item: ListItem = self.index[uid]
        if self.head == item:
            self.head = item.prev
        if self.tail == item:
            self.tail = item.next
        if item.next:
            item.next.prev = item.prev
        if item.prev:
            item.prev.next = item.next

        del item.next
        del item.prev
        del item
        del self.index[uid]
```

This is the code i used for testing:

```
import indexedLinkedList
import tracemalloc


tracemalloc.start()
cache = indexedLinkedList.LinkedList()
print(tracemalloc.get_traced_memory())
cache_len = 1000

for i in range(cache_len):
    cache.append(i, i)
print(tracemalloc.get_traced_memory())
for i in range(cache_len):
    cache.remove(i)
print(tracemalloc.get_traced_memory())

for j in range(1000):
    for i in range(cache_len):
       cache.append(i, i)
    for i in range(cache_len):
        cache.remove(i)
print(tracemalloc.get_traced_memory())
```

After each cycle of adding 1000 elements and removing them the memory is growing.

This linked list is much faster in removing items compared to list or "deque from collections"
inserting/appending is a "bit" slower but is negligible.

1. I tried doing del on different places in the code.
2. objgraph.show_most_common_types() doesnt show me an increased number of objects.
3. gc.collect() still doesnt bring it close to the numbers I expect.
4. profile also didn't show me where it was. it shows 0.0 MiB increases
   `from memory_profiler import profile  @profile`

Anyone have any tips for me?

Comment: `del` does not actually delete items from memory, it only removes a reference. Only once all references to the item are gone out of scope is the item deleted by the garbage collector.

Comment: There should be no other references.
I just retested some more, If i put it in a longer for loop it only grows for the first x seconds of running this code. with a cache size of 5000.

It gives steady results.
After appending it is:
(1839673, 1853412)
After removing it is:
(325253, 1853412)

I will have to see how it behaves with larger datasets.

Comment: Tested with larger datasets and changing indexes/uids over time. It seems to be more python core related. With larger datasets the size is not growing. the cleaned up state doesnt grow. it is only during the first second that it grows. further usage doesnt grow it any further. ofcourse adding items will make it grow. but after removing it is small again.

Comment: I ran the adding and removing in a loop ten times. After the third iteration it stabilized and didn't increase any further